# Можно ли установить на один компьютер ubuntu server и ubuntu desktop?

Tags: ubuntu

Имеется ноутбук с двумя абсолютно одинаковыми ssd на один установлена ubuntu desktop на другой ubuntu server, но при запуске компьютера не выпадает выбор между операционными системами (запускается ubuntu desktop), что делать? Можно ли их использовать таким образом?

Comment: установите нужные вам пакеты, и назовите это как хотите: хоть "ubuntu server", хоть "ubuntu desktop", хоть "ubuntu с набором нужных мне пакетов"

Comment: А смысл ставить 2 убунты в которых из различий - только иксы?

Answer (score 2):

нужно поставить os-prober если не стоит.

```
sudo apt install os-prober
sudo update-grub
```